# BlackBerry: Overriding paint() vs subpaint()

Tags: java, blackberry

When making a custom field, what should I consider between overriding the `paint()` vs `subpaint()` methods to render custom parts of a field?

My code currently overrides `paint()`, but I just read the javadoc which suggests to implement the `subpaint()` method. In my very simple custom fields (like a custom banner with gradient fill), the only difference I can see is that if I override `paint()`, then I must call `super.paint()`, but if I override `subpaint()` then there is no need to call `super.subpaint()`.

I realise that for more advanced customisations, there would be some considerations to take into account, and it is highly likely that one of the approaches might be considered poor practice.

Should I change my base approach (and those in my company) to choose to override `subpaint()` by default in the future?

(I hope this is not considered a discussion question - that is not my intent - thanks)

Comment: If you create a custom `Field` from zero, then there is no `Field.subpaint()` method in the API, so there's the only way - to override/implement `Field.paint()`. On the other hand `subpaint()` is related to customizing/implementing a `Manager`. I've never used `subpaint()` in my practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subpaint()` is really used for Managers, not necessarily a custom Field (yeah, Manager is a Field). It's default implementation is to just loop through its child Fields and issue a `paintChild()` call on it. `paint()`, on the other hand, is for the Field to do drawing related to itself. In your case, you should be overriding `paint()`.

So why would you override `subpaint()`? You would want to if you need child Fields to paint themselves in a certain order. Say that you have a custom Manager that places some Fields on top of each other. If they need to be painted in a certain order, you would override `subpaint()` to make sure the right Field is "on top." Also, a Manager's `paint()` will call its `subpaint()`, something to keep in mind if you override it.

Comment: So are you saying something like `paint()` does the actual painting of the field being created, while `subpaint()` doesn't do the painting itself, but calls to the child fields instead? (in a general, convention type of way, since that's really what this is about...)

Comment: Yep, you've got it! From the `subpaint()` description in a Manager: Implements custom paint features for this manager. Your implementation of this method should instruct all controlled fields in your Manager to paint themselves. Optimize this method by using details of the layout to determine which fields are in the current visible region. To paint a controlled field, invoke Manager.paintChild().

By default, this method paints all child fields, without regard to the clipping region.