# BlackBerry - setBanner() vs setTitle()

Tags: blackberry

As with my previous "vs" question at [BlackBerry: Overriding paint() vs subpaint()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755504/blackberry-overriding-paint-vs-subpaint) I am wondering if this has to do mostly with convention, style, or if there are some real hard n fast rules.

The way I've seen it so far is that `MainScreen.setBanner(Field)` and `MainScreen.setTitle(Field)` have almost exactly the same functionality. I have used the case of being able to call `setTitle(String)` in a simple UI. However I am working across iOS, droid, BB, and try to make the UIs similar - my title/banner is a 'pretty' custom manager.

The only difference I can see is the little style element that is inserted automatically under a title.

Is this the only reason I would have to choose between using each of these methods?

Perhaps there are stylistic or convention reasons to use one over the other? Perhaps RIM has some intentions with these methods that I cannot yet see as a new BB developer? Am I making a mistake by treating these methods as direct substitutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use both, the banner is laid out above the title.  My understanding is that if you are using only one, then they are pretty much interchangeable -- the reason to have both is that you can get some stacking behavior if you want to add more information to the top of the screen.

Comment: There is a pretty big difference, the title is themed with a separator. This thread has a little info and a way around the themed separator : http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Title-bar-without-gap/m-p/447512#M88595

Comment: @Dan in my current understanding, this can more easily be accomplished by adding the field to the banner section instead of creating a non scrolling field in that way. But it is this understanding that I am challenging or confirming with this question. Thx for the code though.

Comment: @Dan Good to know. The banner isn't themed then, just the title?

Comment: the banner does not have the separator theme included, no.
Yeah, as for the code, I just wanted to give you an example of the difference in play, I do not endorse any code from the forums there, unless peter_strange, simon_hain or MSohm do  :D

Comment: @Dan yes peter_strange really does know the platform well. The part I found useful in the code was the call to super(NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL). Anyway thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article: "[MainScreen explained](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/MainScreen-explained/td-p/605580)" that goes into detail on this and other features of MainScreen.