# When to use subpaint() and super.paint() method for Manager class in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, paint, super

I need to know when to use a `super.paint()` and `subpaint()` method in Blackberry for Manager class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use subPaint when you are `Implementing your own layout manager`. subpaint() should iterate through all the controlled fields, instructing them to paint themselves. You can optimize subpaint by using details of the layout to determine which fields are in the current visible region. To paint a controlled field, invoke paintchild. else you can use `super.paint()`.

see the [documentation for more detail](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.6api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html).

And see this answer for more clarification [BlackBerry: Overriding paint() vs subpaint()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755504/blackberry-overriding-paint-vs-subpaint)